# The variable that store the rank of my process seems to change for values that make no sens

Tags: mpi

So, for a reason that I do not understand, the values of my variables myrank and numberOfProcess used in the MPI function `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numberOfProcess); and MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);` have their values changed.

Here is my code :

```
int myrank, numberOfProcess;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numberOfProcess);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

for(k = 0; k < iteration; k++{
    
    /*some computation*/

   
   printf("numberOfProcess : %d myrank : %d, k : %d\n", numberOfProcess, myrank, k);
   MPI_Allgather(sendBuf, sendSize, MPI_DOUBLE, rcvBuf, rcvSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}
```

The output from the printf function :

```
numberOfProcess : 2, myrank : 1, k : 0
numberOfProcess : 1077202124, myrank : -858993459, k : 1
numberOfProcess : 2, myrank : 0, k : 0
numberOfProcess : 1077202124, myrank : -858993459, k : 1
```

As you can see, in the second iteration of the loop, the values of the variables numberOfProcess and myrank make no sense at all.

I am running that code with `mpirun -np 2` and `iteration = 3`

Unfortunately, I can't show you more of my code since it is confidential.
Do you have any idea why this is happening, and what are the solutions to resolve this issue ?

Edit : I never found any solution for that issue. I hardcoded a function to replace Allgather and it resolve the problem.

Comment: This is likely a buffer overflow: `rcvBuf` is too small. How did you allocate it?

Comment: It also indicates that your send buffer is on the stack which may not be a good idea if it gets large. Use dynamic allocation.